# Как протестировать мобильную версию сайта?

Tags: адаптивная-верстка

Как посмотреть как выглядит содержимое в iphone и windows phone??
[введите сюда описание ссылки](http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/) пробывал данный сайт но он не открывает почему-то сайт. Подскажите какие вы используете инструменты?

Comment: [**BrowserStack**](https://www.browserstack.com) бесплатен для Open Source проектов. iPhone и Windows Phone поддерживаются. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть бесплатный онлайн инструмент для тестирования на физических мобильных - это **[WebPagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org/)**. Там есть выбор для локации, устройства и браузера. Очень удобен для анализа производительности: после получения результат, щелкните на ***Waterfall*** и далее на наиболее длинные бары, которыми обозначены критические ресурсы вашего веб-сайта. Этот инструмент рекомендован Гугл. Также вы можете использовать инструмент для этой цели **[MobileTest](http://mobiletest.me/)**.

Comment: там скриншоты выдаются я так понимаю только. Мне нужно проверить работоспособность полей, форм и прочего

Comment: Эти скриншорты и показывают работоспособность каждого ресурса вашего веб-сайта.

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Google Chrome Dev Tool Вам в помощь

Comment: Chrome показывает, как будет вести себя Хром на этом устройстве. А если надо проверить Сафари, то он не поможет.

Comment: Понятно, что лучше иметь устройство под рукой...

Comment: Есть эмуляторы, только мне известны лишь платные...